# glutMainLoopEvent function cause memory leak

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks

I have a main function in a single main.cpp. Basically, it first call the update function to update command for rendering and then calling the rendering function to render the scene. The rendering function is in another single cpp files.

In order to prevent glutMainLoop() function from blocking updating command in the main function, I use glutMainLoopEvent() in freeglut package as instead.

In my rendering function, the code

```
glmDraw(Model, GLM_SMOOTH|GLM_TEXTURE|GLM_MATERIAL);
```

is used to render the scene. If I use glutMainLoop(), this code above will be only executed only once in rendering function. However, when I use glutMainLoopEvent() function, this code will be executed again and again and cause the memory leak problem.

Any suggestion for correcting it?

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak would be somewhere in your code. Double check that all memory you have allocated is getting deallocated properly in your render function. Its your code getting called again and again and leaking memory not glut.